# solving an inexact differential equation when an integrating factor cannot be found

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm just reading ahead for my DE class, and there isn't really an answer for when the integrating factor can't be found in terms of purely $x$ or purely $y$:

http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/first/intfactor/intfactor.html

What sort of techniques are there to handle this?  Please suggest edits if the question is too broad rather than voting to close (I am new to DE so not sure how to ask the question)

Comment: There is no general method.

Comment: You should try making susbstitutions or manipulate the expression somehow to make it a total differential

Comment: Unfortunately, if that happens, you'll need to find another method to solve the equation. It'd help if you could provide a specific example equation. However, the new method will depend on the equation.

Comment: i found this question, maybe will help you with the problem that you want to solve, or if was curiosity only
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/428216/546265
You can try Numerically, with any CAS.