# How to solve a first order, non-linear, non-separable ordinary differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $\gamma>0$, $\kappa>0$, $\nu>0$ and $\beta <0$. In [modeling financial time series](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0403563) one considers a following first order, non-linear, non-separable Ordinary Differential Equation(ODE). We have:

\begin{equation}
M(x,y) dx + N(x,y) dy = 0 \quad (i)
\end{equation}

where

\begin{eqnarray}
M(x,y) &=& - \left[ \sinh(\gamma x+ \kappa y) - y \cosh(\gamma x+ \kappa y) \right]\\
N(x,y) &=& \mu \left[ \sinh(\beta y) - x \cosh(\beta y) \right]
\end{eqnarray}

My objective in here is to solve this equation at least for some particular parameter values. One way to tackle this problem would be to find an integration factor $\mu(\omega) $, where $\omega = \omega(x,y)$, such that by multiplying that factor into the coefficients $M(x,y)$ and $N(x,y)$ in $(i)$ we turn it into a total differential. We other words we want to obtain another ODE as follows:

\begin{equation}
\bar{M}(x,y) dx + \bar{N}(x,y) dy = 0 \quad (ii)
\end{equation}

where $(\bar{M}(x,y),\bar{N}(x,y))= \exp(\omega) \cdot (M(x,y),N(x,y))$  such that $\partial_y \bar{M}(x,y) = \partial_x \bar{N}(x,y)$. It is not hard to show, see [Finding integrating factor for inexact differential equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428216/finding-integrating-factor-for-inexact-differential-equation?rq=1) for example, that the function $\omega$ has to satisfy a following Partial Differential Equation:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial x} \cdot N(x,y) - \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial y} \cdot M(x,y) = \frac{\partial M}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial N}{\partial x} \quad (iii)
\end{equation}

---

In our case equation $(iii)$ looks much more complicated than the original ODE $(i)$ and we do not know how to solve it. However we can also expand the coefficients in series and truncate the expansion at the second order and solve the resulting approximated equation. In other words we have:

\begin{eqnarray}
&&\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial x} \cdot \mu (-x + \beta y) + \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial y} \cdot (\gamma x + (\kappa-1) y) = \left(-\kappa +\mu +1\right) +\\
&& \frac{1}{2} y^2 \left(\beta ^2 \mu -\kappa ^3+3 \kappa ^2\right)-\frac{1}{2} \gamma ^2 (\kappa -1)
   x^2-\gamma  (\kappa -2) \kappa  x y \quad (iiia)
\end{eqnarray}

In here we make a conjecture $\omega = \omega^{(1)} + \omega^{(2)}$ where:
\begin{eqnarray}
\omega^{(1)} &=& {\mathcal A}_{1,1} x^2 + {\mathcal A}_{1,2} x y + {\mathcal A}_{2,2} y^2 \\
\omega^{(2)} &=& \log\left[ \sum\limits_{j=0}^{{\mathfrak O}} {\mathfrak A}_j x^{{\mathfrak O}-j} y^j\right]
\end{eqnarray}
for some ${\mathfrak O} \in {\mathbb N} $.

The first and the second part of the solution are such that being inserted into the left hand side of the PDE $(iiia)$ they produce  firstly the constant and secondly the quadratic form on the right hand side.

Now, the coefficients of the first part of the solution read:

\begin{eqnarray}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
{\mathcal A}_{1,1} \\{\mathcal A}_{1,2} \\ {\mathcal A}_{2,2}
\end{array}
\right)&=&
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -2 \mu  & \gamma  & 0 \\
 2 \beta  \mu  & \kappa-1-\mu  & 2 \gamma  \\
 0 & \beta  \mu  & 2(\kappa-1) \\
\end{array}
\right)^{-1} \cdot
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 -\frac{1}{2} \gamma ^2 (\kappa -1) \\
 -\gamma  (\kappa -2) \kappa  \\
 \frac{1}{2} \left(\beta ^2 \mu -\kappa ^3+3 \kappa ^2\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{eqnarray}

And the coefficients of the second part of the solution read:

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum\limits_{j=0}^{{\mathfrak O}} {\mathfrak M}_{i,j} \cdot {\mathfrak A}_j = 0
\quad \mbox{for $i=0,\cdots,{\mathfrak O}$}
\end{eqnarray}

where

\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathfrak M}_{i,j} =
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
(i+1)(K)- ({\mathfrak O}-i+1)\mu & \mbox{if $j=i$} \\
({\mathfrak O}-i+1) \beta \mu & \mbox{if $j=i-1$} \\
(i+1) \gamma & \mbox{if $j=i+1$} \\
0 & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{eqnarray}

and

\begin{eqnarray}
&&\det\left( {\mathfrak M}_{i,j}  \right)_{i,j=1}^{{\mathfrak O}} =\\
&&
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
\prod\limits_{j=1}^{\frac{({\mathfrak O}+1)}{2}}
\left([j (K)-({\mathfrak O}+2-j) \mu] \cdot [ ({\mathfrak O}+2-j) (K)-j \mu] - ({\mathfrak O} - 2(j-1))^2 \beta \gamma \mu\right)
& \quad \mbox{if ${\mathfrak O}$ is odd} \\
(\frac{{\mathfrak O}}{2}+1)\left(K-\mu\right)
\prod\limits_{j=1}^{\frac{({\mathfrak O})}{2}}
\left([j (K)-({\mathfrak O}+2-j) \mu] \cdot [ ({\mathfrak O}+2-j) (K)-j \mu] - ({\mathfrak O} - 2(j-1))^2 \beta \gamma \mu\right)
& \quad \mbox{if ${\mathfrak O}$ is even}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{eqnarray}

subject to  $ \det\left( {\mathfrak M}_{i,j}  \right)_{i,j=1}^{{\mathfrak O}} = 0 $. Here we denoted $ K:= \kappa-1 $.

Below I am presenting a Mathematica code that derives and verifies all those results above.

Firstly let's go for the first part of the solution:

```
(*The solution omega1; The regular solution.*)
Clear[A]; Clear[omega]; mu =.; kappa =.; Kappa =.; gamma =.; beta =.; \
x =.; y =.; ord = 2;(*Kappa=kappa-1*)
omega[x_, y_] := Sum[A[j] x^(ord - j) y^j, {j, 0, ord}];
myeqn = mu (- x + beta y) D[omega[x, y], x] + (gamma x + (Kappa) y) D[
     omega[x, y], y] - (-(1/2) gamma^2 (-1 + kappa) x^2 - 
     gamma (-2 + kappa) kappa x y + 
     1/2 (3 kappa^2 - kappa^3 + beta^2 mu) y^2);


myvars = Flatten[Table[A[j], {j, 0, ord}]];
mat = Table[
   Coefficient[
    Coefficient[myeqn, x^(ord - j) y^j] /. {x :> 0, y :> 0}, 
    myvars[[i]]], {j, 0, ord}, {i, 1, Length[myvars]}];
rhs = -Simplify[(Table[
       Coefficient[myeqn, x^(ord - j) y^j] /. {x :> 0, y :> 0}, {j, 0,
         ord}] /. A[i_] :> 0)];
MatrixForm[#] & /@ {mat, rhs}
Det[mat] // FullSimplify
sol = Simplify[(Inverse[mat].rhs)];
For[j = 0, j <= ord, j++, A[j] = sol[[1 + j]]];

(mu (- x + beta y) D[omega[x, y], x] + (gamma x + (Kappa) y) D[
     omega[x, y], y] - (-(1/2) gamma^2 (-1 + kappa) x^2 - 
     gamma (-2 + kappa) kappa x y + 
     1/2 (3 kappa^2 - kappa^3 + beta^2 mu) y^2)) // Simplify
```

[image]

Now let us go for the second part of the solution. We have:

```
(*The solution omega2; The singular solution.*)
Clear[A]; Clear[omega]; mu =.; kappa =.; Kappa =.; gamma =.; beta =.; \
x =.; y =.; ord = 6;(*Kappa=kappa-1*)
omega[x_, y_] := Log[Sum[A[j] x^(ord - j) y^j, {j, 0, ord}]];
myeqn = mu (- x + beta y) D[omega[x, y], x] + (gamma x + (Kappa) y) D[
     omega[x, y], y] - (mu - Kappa);
mynum = Collect[Numerator[Together[myeqn]], {x, y}, Simplify];

myvars = Table[A[j], {j, 0, ord}]; numvars = ord + 1;
mat = Table[
   Coefficient[
    Coefficient[mynum, x^(ord - j) y^j] /. {x :> 0, y :> 0}, 
    myvars[[i]]], {j, 0, ord}, {i, 1, Length[myvars]}];
MatrixForm[mat]
dd = FullSimplify[Det[mat]];
Fold[Times, 
  1, (Collect[#[[1]], Kappa, Simplify]^#[[2]]) & /@ FactorList[dd]];

(*Find the constants A[j] j=0,..,ord*)
cfs = Flatten[
   Table[Coefficient[mynum, x^(ord - j) y^j] /. {x :> 0, y :> 0}, {j, 
     0, ord}]];
Subst = {};
While[True,
  ii0 = NaN;
  For[ii = 1, ii <= Length[cfs], ii++,
   ids = Flatten[
     Position[
      Table[! FreeQ[cfs[[ii]], myvars[[j]]], {j, 1, 
        numvars}], _?(# == True &)]];
   If[! (ids == {}), ii0 = ii; Break[]];
   ];
  If[ii0 == NaN, Break[]];
  subst = 
   Simplify@Flatten[Solve[cfs[[ii0]] == 0, myvars[[#]] & /@ ids]];
  Subst = Join[Subst, subst];
  cfs = DeleteCases[Simplify[cfs //. Subst], 0];
  (*Determine which variables have been eliminated*)
  which = 
   Position[
    Table[FreeQ[cfs, myvars[[j]]], {j, 1, numvars}], _?(# == True &)];
  myvars = Delete[myvars, which]; numvars = Length[myvars];(*Print[
  cfs,myvars];Input["Press any key"];*)
  If[numvars == 1, Break[]];
  ];
Collect[mynum /. Subst, {x, y}, FullSimplify]
MatrixForm[Subst]
```

[image]

---

Having said all this my question would be the following.  How do we solve the PDE $(iii)$ in general? Does the solution always exist? Can we also obtain a solution, either to $(iii)$ or to $(iiia)$, without imposing any constraints on the parameters?

Comment: In general the PDE that you get for the integrating factor is a transport equation: $a(x,y) \omega_x + b(x,y) \omega_y = c(x,y)$. You can in principle solve it by the method of characteristics, though even when $a$ and $b$ are both never zero, you can still have problems with colliding characteristics.

Comment: That being said, identifying the characteristics of this equation *analytically* without imposing any ansatz about $\omega$ is essentially as difficult as solving the original equation, since the characteristics just satisfy $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{M}{N}$ which is exactly what you want to get out of the ODE in the first place. Integrating factors don't really provide any "free lunch" in this respect.

Comment: @Ian: Well, one has to solve the PDE (iiii) in a different way, i.e. by making an ansatz. I have not achieved this yet but I did achieve it for (iiia) and I am confident  that by adding higher order terms to (iiia) I can guess  similar solutions and as such even obtain a solution to (iii) in the first place.